# How to colour link annotation or add action to highlight annotation using PdfKit in swift

Tags: xcode10, ios12, swift4.2, ios-pdfkit

I have some pdf's in my application and am using PdfKit in swift. Now i want to highlight all the hyperlinks in a pdf document. I tried using PDFAnnotationSubtype.highlight and PDFAnnotationSubtype.link but in both cases i could not achieve my goal.

**For PDFAnnotationSubtype.highlight - on click of links i could not add action to it.**

**For PDFAnnotationSubtype.link - i could not set color or background color to links.**

Here is my code please correct me if am missing something here.

```
//here i get my pdf from document directory
let filePAth = (self.getDirectoryPath() as NSString).appendingPathComponent(webURLString)
    let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePAth)

    let document = PDFDocument(url: fileURL)

    self.pdfView.displayMode = .twoUpContinuous
    self.pdfView.displayDirection = .horizontal
     pdfView.usePageViewController(true, withViewOptions: [UIPageViewController.OptionsKey.interPageSpacing: 0])

    //here is the hack 
    //i am getting annotation  
   let count = document?.pageCount

    for i in 0 ..< count! {

        let page = document?.page(at: i)
        let annotationArray = page1?.annotations

      for annotationObj in annotationArray! {
            if annotationObj.type! == "Link" {

                //case 1: highlights hyperlinks links but
                //added action does not work
                let annotation = PDFAnnotation(bounds: obj.bounds, forType: PDFAnnotationSubtype.highlight, withProperties: nil)

                annotation.color = UIColor.red
                annotation.isHighlighted = true

                // highlights all the hyperlinks with red color
                // but added action does not work here

                let url = URL(string: "http://google.com/")
                annotation.action = PDFActionURL(url: url!)

               page?.addAnnotation(annotation)

             //case 2: does not highlights hyperlinks links with red 
             //color but added action works

                let annotation = PDFAnnotation(bounds: obj.bounds, forType: PDFAnnotationSubtype.link, withProperties: nil)
                // no effect 
                annotation.color = UIColor.red
                annotation.isHighlighted = true

                // does not highlight all the hyperlinks with red 
                // but added action works here

                let url = URL(string: "http://google.com/")
                annotation.action = PDFActionURL(url: url!)

               page?.addAnnotation(annotation)

            }
        }
    }
```

I am able out find the way. can anyone suggest somethings?
Image is result of case 1 mentioned in the code.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even it is not a proper solution, though it is a hack.

Step 1 - Create link annotation and add existing annotation action to new link annotation.

```
let linkAnnotation = PDFAnnotation(bounds: obj.bounds, forType: PDFAnnotationSubtype.link, withProperties: nil)
linkAnnotation.action = obj.annotation
```

Step 2 - Add new link annotation to page after your highlighted annotation.

```
page?.addAnnotation(linkAnnotation)
```

Try and let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need add any action to annotation, you can get it for free by adding notification observe because PDFKit will post notification named 'PDFViewAnnotationHit' when an annotation be clicked. [Here is Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1504809-pdfviewannotationhit)

```
func addAnnotationNotification() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(annotationHit(notification:)),
        name: Notification.Name.PDFViewAnnotationHit, object: nil
    )
}

@objc func annotationHit(notification: Notification) {
    if let annotation = notification.userInfo?["PDFAnnotationHit"] as? PDFAnnotation {
        print(annotation.bounds)
        print(annotation.contents!)
    }
}
```